# access object outside through an abstract function

Tags: php, class, static-methods

Given the following classes:

```
<?php
class test{
static public function statfunc()
    {
    echo "this is the static function<br/>";
            $api= new object;

    }   
}

class traductor
{

    public function display()
    {
       echo "this is the object function";
}
}

test::statfunc();

$api->display();
```

This does not display the message `"this is the static function<br/>"`.

Is there a way to instantiate through a static function and get that object outside?

Thanks... I am inexperienced regarding object programming code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return the object from your static function:

```
static public function statfunc()
{
    $api = new traductor;
    return $api;
}
```

And then store the returned object in a variable that you can use.

```
$api = test::statfunc();
$api->display();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help simple and fast! Thanks for the edit also.

Answer (score 2):

Your use of declaration is a bit off. Your code results in 2 fatal errors. First, class object is not found, you should replace:

```
$api= new object;
```

With

```
return new traductor;
```

Being a static class, they perform an action, they don't hold data, hence the static keyword. Down the line when you start working with $this and etc, remember that. You need to return the result to another variable.

```
test::statfunc();
$api->display();
```

Should become:

```
$api = test::statfunc();
$api->display();
```

See, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php for some more information on static keywords and examples.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I'll take a look at the link you provided with.